# Trying to create a sequence in Oracle that starts with the max value of primary key of a specific table. Why does this not work?

Tags: oracle

Trying to create a sequence in Oracle that starts with the max value from a specific table. Why does this not work ?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE reservation_sequence
MINVALUE 0
START WITH (SELECT MAX(reservation_id)
 FROM reservation) 
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 20;
```

Comment: 'This does not work' is hardly an error code in any system.  What's more, it does not describe your problem at all.  Do you get an error?  Or you get a sequence with the wrong values?  Or?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798766/how-to-create-an-oracle-sequence-starting-with-max-value-from-a-table Did you copy this question? the wording looks strangely familiar !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot mix DDL with DML in this way.

Your best bet is an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE
seqval NUMBER;
  BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(nvl(reservation_id),0)
  INTO seqval
  FROM reservation;

  execute immediate('CREATE SEQUENCE reservation_sequence MINVALUE 0 START WITH '||seqval||' INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20');
  END;
END;
/
```

Plus, are you sure you want `max()` and not `max()+1`?

Comment: It might not be relevant for the question, but I see this only be used to reproduce `AUTO_INCREMENT` functionality. In that case, why would you use a `SEQUENCE` for this and not [define it inline](http://pastebin.com/HjHPuwUm)? (Was not sure if I should create new question).

Comment: The OP actually wants to create a sequence for further use, that's why. What you propose does not actually guarantee sequentiality when used as a sequence. The OP would only have used the code in this answer once to initially create the sequence

Answer (score 1):

In the [Oracle SQL Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF55572) you can find a 
[syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/img_text/create_sequence.htm)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [ schema. ] sequence
   [ { INCREMENT BY | START WITH } integer
   | { MAXVALUE integer | NOMAXVALUE }
   | { MINVALUE integer | NOMINVALUE }
   | { CYCLE | NOCYCLE }
   | { CACHE integer | NOCACHE }
   | { ORDER | NOORDER }
   ]...
;
```

so START WITH must be followed by an integer and nothing else. An integer is also difined by a [syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/img_text/integer.htm) in this [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51059)
(to find the syntax diagram for integers look at the [index of the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/index.htm#I)

```
[ + | - ] digit [ digit ]...
```

The error you will get will be

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

The description of the error can be found in [one of the manuals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/e1500.htm#sthref843), too.

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
Cause: The specified number was invalid.
Action: Specify a valid number.
```

If you look at your error it may be that also the exact position where the error occurs in the statement may be displayed.